# python training and testing models from command line

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

How to train the model using

```
$ python train.py --train_file train.txt
```

and test the model using

```
$ python test.py --input_file test.txt --output_file result.txt
```

How to tell python that two commands are related to each other?

Answer (score 1):

You should add command-line args parser (for example [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html)) in your program.